# Getting xml file inside Jar file

Tags: java, xml, exception, jar, static-methods

I'm using NetBeans and i wrote this function, with help of other thread to a same question,
but i get error of line "`InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(xml_file_path);`"
saying: "`non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context`"

```
public static Document Get_XML_Document_From_Jar(String xml_file_path) {
    Document xml_doc = null;

    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(xml_file_path);
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        xml_doc = db.parse(is);                          // just use a different parse method   
        xml_doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return xml_doc;
}
```

what can i do?
i tryied using ClassLoader but didn't succeed.

Comment: Lots of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getResourceAsStream

Answer (score 4):

```
non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

You must use:

```
YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream()
```

instead of `getClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xml_file_path);
```